# runlevel 2 and 5 works the same on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

the post [Starting Your Software Automatically on Boot](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html) explains 
that the run level 2 will start the system in full production with NFS and 
runlevel 5 will support the full system with additional graphic support. 
the `runlevel` command will show the previous and current runlevel and 
`telinit` will change the system runlevel.

I tried both, command `runlevel` shows me

```
  N 2
```

which means that the current runlevel is 2. But the system is running in 
graphic mode (I am using ubuntu 12.10). So, my question is, why the current
runlevel of Ubuntu is 2 though I am running the graphic system.

Then I tried to use `telinit 5` command with root privilege, change the 
current runlevel to 5 and reboot the system. The system reboots in a proper 
way, running the gnome-session as usual. However, when I run the 
`runlevel` again after the reboot, it still shows

```
  N 2
```

I am confused with such kind of result, because I have changed it the 5. 
Could you tell me why?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

snip below from http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

4.7   Runlevels

A runlevel is a single-byte name for a particular system configuration. Runlevels for Debian and Ubuntu systems are generally as follows [30]:

```
0 : System halt.
1 : Single-User mode.
2 : Graphical multi-user plus networking (DEFAULT)
3 : Same as "2", but not used.
4 : Same as "2", but not used.
5 : Same as "2", but not used.
6 : System reboot.
```

Answer (score 1):

Various flavours of Linux, and even other UNIX implementations as well (such as AIX, HPUX and Solaris), have subtly different uses for each runlevel.

For example, RHEL and SLES generally comes up in runlevel 5, Ubuntu (as you've seen) comes up in runlevel 2.

And `telinit` simply changes the *current* runlevel, it won't survive a reboot. If you want to change the default boot-time runlevel, you need to look into `/etc/inittab` for a line like:

```
id:2:initdefault:
```